# I have a question about my program that reads 2 sentences entered by a user, then compares them in various ways

Tags: python-3.x

I am brand new to Python, and I am trying to write a program that reads two sentences provided by a user, then compares them in the following ways:

I. It has to display a list of all the unique words contained in both sentences.

II. It has to display a list of the words that appear in both sentences.

III. It has to display a list of the words that appear in the first sentence but not the second.

IV. It has to display a list of the words that appear in the second sentence but not the first.

V. It has to display a list of the words that appear in either the first or second sentence but not both.

I tried searching for my issue on this site, but I could not find anything that exactly describes my problem. I have tried reading my book (Learning Python - 5th Ed), and even searched the web for pointers on how to get my program to function correctly.

Here is my code, I apologize in advance, as I know this is not the most efficient way to approach this type of program; but I am brand new to Python, and I could not think of a better way:

def sentenceDisplay():

```
userSentence1 = input('Please enter your first sentence: ')
userSentence2 = input('Please enter your second sentence: ')

sentDisplay1 = userSentence1.split()
sentDisplay2 = userSentence2.split()

print('The words contained within sentence #1 is: ', sentDisplay1)
print('The words contained within sentence #2 is: ', sentDisplay2)
```

sentenceDisplay()

def sent1And2Display():

```
userSent1 = input('Please enter your first sentence: ')
userSent2 = input('Please enter your second sentence: ')

displaySent1And2 = set(userSent1).union(set(userSent2))

displaySent1And2 = (userSent1.split() + userSent2.split())

print('The words contained within both sentence #1 and #2 is: ' + str(displaySent1And2))
```

sent1And2Display()

def diffOfUnion():

```
uSent1 = input('Please enter your first sentence: ')
uSent2 = input('Please enter your second sentence: ')

set1And2 = [set(uSent1), set(uSent2)]

nonRepSet = []

for sentSetElm in set1And2:
    nonRepSet.append(len(sentSetElm.difference(set.union(*[i for i in set1And2 if i is not sentSetElm]))))

print('The unique words contained within both sentences is: ', (nonRepSet))
```

diffOfUnion()

def symmDiff():

```
symmSent1 = input('Please enter your first sentence: ')
symmSent2 = input('Please enter your second sentence: ')

symmDiffSent1And2 = set(symmSent1).symmetric_difference(set(symmSent2))

symmDiffSent1And2 = (symmSent1.split()+ symmSent2.split())

print('The words contained in either sentence #1 and #2, but not both is: ' + str(symmDiffSent1And2))
```

symmDiff()

I know that using set operations is what I need to do, but my functions (#3 and #4) are not behaving as they should; function #3 is showing the answer as a set of integers, but I need it to display as a set of strings like the rest of my functions. Also, function #4 is not finding the symmetric difference of the two sentences, and I cannot quite figure out as to why.

Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and sweet.

```
sent1 = "A random sentence.".split()
sent2 = "Some other random sentence.".split()

diff = set(sent1) ^ set(sent2)
union = set(sent1) & set(sent2)
one_not_two = set(sent1) - set(sent2)
two_not_one = set(sent2) - set(sent1)
all_words = sent1 + sent2


print(f"I. The word(s) contained in both sentence #1 and #2: {', '.join(union)}")
print(f"II. All word(s) from either: {', '.join(all_words)}")
print(f"III. The word(s) contained in sentence #1 only: {', '.join(one_not_two)}")
print(f"IV. The word(s) contained in sentence #2 only: {', '.join(two_not_one)}")
print(f"V.The word(s) contained in either sentence #1 or #2, but not both: {', '.join(diff)}")
```

I. The word(s) contained in both sentence #1 and #2: sentence., random

II. All word(s) from either: A, random, sentence., Some, other, random, sentence.

III. The word(s) contained in sentence #1 only: A

IV. The word(s) contained in sentence #2 only: Some, other

V.The word(s) contained in either sentence #1 or #2, but not both: A, Some, other

Comment: Thank you. I have modified my code to closer reflect yours, but I still wanted the program to ask for 2 sentences entered by a user - I managed to get it to work and display the results in the form of a list (by editing my print statements). And no, actually, it was a request by a coworker to see if I was capable of writing such a program. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, I left out the input section so that the example would make sense and since you already had it. Glad I could help. Best of luck with your work. : )